# In ES2015 how can I ensure all methods wait for object to initialize ? With ES7 decorators?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, decorator, ecmascript-next

I have an ES2015 class that connects to a remote service.

The problem is that my code tries to access this class before its object has finished connecting to the remote server.

I want to ensure that methods don't just give an error if the object has not finished initializing.

I'll have alot of methods in my class that depend on the connection being up and running, so it would be good if there was a single, easy to understand mechanism that could be applied to all methods like an @ensureConnected decorator.

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/mct6ss19/2/

```
'use strict';

class Server {
    helloWorld() {
        return "Hello world"
    }
}

class Client {
    constructor() {
            this.connection = null
            this.establishConnection()
    }

    establishConnection() {
        // simulate slow connection setup by initializing after 2 seconds
        setTimeout(() => {this.connection= new Server()}, 2000)
    }

    doSomethingRemote() {
            console.log(this.connection.helloWorld())
    }

}

let test = new Client();
// doesn't work because we try immediately after object initialization
test.doSomethingRemote();
// works because the object has had time to initialize
setTimeout(() => {test.doSomethingRemote()}, 3000)
```

I was imaging using ES7 decorators to implement a test to see if the connection is established but I can't see how to do so.

Comment: Add a callback parameter to your  Client constructor, pass it a callback function, call that function after the server responds, and call the other client methods from the callback.

Comment: FYI, decorators are not part of ES7 (ES2016).

Comment: related: [Is it bad practice to have a constructor function return a Promise?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24398699/1048572) - create your instances only once they are ready.

Comment: If a coder does call the method before the connection is established, what should the method do other than throw an error? It's the best behavior as far as I can tell.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are JavaScript ES6 Classes of any use with asynchronous code bases?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37556058/1048572)

Answer (score 3):

I would not initiate the connection in the constructor. Constructors are more designed for initializing variables, etc., rather than program logic. I would instead call `establishConnection` yourself from your client code.

If you want to do this in the constructor, store the result in an instance variable, and then wait for it in `doSomethingRemote`, as in:

```
class Client {
    constructor() {
        this.connection = this.establishConnection();
    }

    establishConnection() {
        // simulate slow connection setup by initializing after 2 seconds
        return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() =>
          resolve(new Server()), 2000));
    }

    doSomethingRemote() {
        this.connection.then(connection => connection.helloWorld());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the end I tried a range of solutions including decorators and using the proxy object.

The solution I went for was to use ES7 async and await.  After quite a bit of futzing around trying to understand how it works and the gotchas, managed to get it working.

So async and await were my most effective solution for ensuring objects had properly initialised.

I also took the advice of @torazaburo (see his answer elsewhere on this page) and ran the initialization method from a factory which first created and then initialized the object.

Comment: Did you `await` in the constructor? How did you work around the fact that constructors can't be `async`?

Comment: @Duke Dougal care to elaborate and show us your function? Would be really helpful ! : )