# why nodejs is giving me error when I use async within class?

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6

```
class Controller {
    async getUser(username) {
        return User.find({username});
    }
}


module.exports = new Controller();
```

**getUser is unexpected identifier**

Why, it works in babel fine.

Comment: What version of node are you using? Sidenote: You'd usually `export default Controller`

Comment: what about module.exports

Comment: It's wierd you create instance when exporting...

Comment: async/await is available since node.js v7.6

Comment: works with 7.4 https://repl.it/K7Ux/0

Comment: i've got 6.4 version

Comment: Either you upgrade your Node version or you configure Babel to work together with Node.

Comment: ok upgraded, it works. But `export default abc;` still wont work

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37556058/are-javascript-es6-classes-of-any-use-with-asynchronous-code-bases