# At an object's instantiation time how does one handle best the asynchronous initialization of one of its properties?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, initialization, instantiation

I've never created a Javascript module/library before so this is a bit new to me so apologizes for my lack of knowing what to google.

I'm creating a library that will hold information from a URL that is provided by a user.  I want to parse the URL's path (the part that comes after the domain) as well as retain a header value that's provided by the URL's response.

It's basic but here's what I have so far:

```
function Link(someURL) {
  this.url = someURL;
  this.urlPath = "";
  this.uuid = "";

  this.getPath = function (someURL) {
    // do regexp parsing and return everything after the domain
  };

  this.getUUID = function (someURL) {
    // fetch the URL and return what is in the response's "uuid" header
  }
}
```

Ideally, I'd the module to automatically get all the information upon construction:

```
var foo = new Link("http://httpbin.org/response-headers?uuid=36d09ff2-4b27-411a-9155-e82210a100c3")
console.log(foo.urlPath);  // should return "uuid"
console.log(foo.uuid);  // should return the contents in the "uuid" header in the response
```

How do I ensure the `this.urlPath` and `this.uuid` properties get initialized along with `this.url`?  Ideally, I'd only fetch the URL once (to prevent rate limiting by the target server).

Comment: Do you need help in the class, in the library structure or both?

Comment: Instead of exporting a `Link` class or factory directly, you should export a configuration function that lets the user provide all the necessary information. This configuration function will then return a factory for `Link` objects, ensuring that all configuration has been supplied

Comment: Always try keeping the footprint of the class / constructor implementation and initialization as small as possible. Implement as much as possible of a class' related computation / helper functionality within the module scope but (,if possible,) not directly connected to the class / constructor. Bonus for the `Link` class: make the computation of the necessary url parts lazy (compute when needed first time) but memorizing (save the lazy computed result / one time computation).

Comment: @PeterSeliger that's what I'm attempting to do but like I said, I'm very new at this.  Once the urlPath and uuid are parsed and retrieved, they don't need to be messed with again but still unsure how to initialize these properties.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of trial and error, I ended up doing something more like this:

```
class Link {
  constructor (url_in) {
    const re = RegExp("^https://somedomain.com\/(.*)$");
    this.url = re[0];
    this.linkPath = re[1];
  }

  async getUUID() {
    const res = await fetch("https://fakedomain.com/getUUID?secret=" + this.linkPath);
    this.uuid = res.uuid;
  }

  async getJSON() {
    const res = await fetch("https://fakedomain.com/getJSON?uuid=" + this.uuid);
    this.json = await res.json();
  }

  async initialize() {
    await this.getUUID();
    await this.getJSON();
  }
}


const someLinkData = new Link("https://reallydumbdomain.com/2020/10/4/blog");
someLinkData.initialize()
  .then(function() {
    console.log(this.json); // this now works
  });
```

I think a future iteration of this will require me to send a promise with the `initialize` function but for now, this works.

Comment: With having landet this approach and already the refactoring in mind, you might, just for your interest, also read ...[*"Are JavaScript ES6 Classes of any use with asynchronous code bases?"*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37556058/are-javascript-es6-classes-of-any-use-with-asynchronous-code-bases).