# How to combine builder pattern with async method calls in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, async-await, reactive-programming, builder

I would like to implement chained method calls like

```
observable
 .pipe(
  filter('foo'),
  add(3)
 )
 .subscribe(subscriber);
```

In order for this to work, the result of `.pipe(...)` must provide the method `subscribe`.

I would like to allow some of the chained method calls (e.g. `pipe`) to by `async`. However, this would breaks my chain because the promise returned by `pipe` does not have a `subscribe` method:

```
await observable
 .pipe(
  filter('foo'),
  add(3)
 )
 .subscribe(subscriber);

async pipe(...operators){
  ...
}
```

=>  `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: observable.pipe(...).subscribe is not a function`

I could rewrite my main code to

```
observable
 .pipe(
  filter('foo'),
  add(3)
 ).then(pipeResult=>
  pipeResult.subscribe(subscriber);
 );
```

However, I find that very ugly to read.

=> Is there a way to apply `await` for each call in the chain of method calls and not only for the last one?

I would expect something like

```
awaitEach observable
 .pipe(
  filter('foo'),
  add(3)
 )
 .subscribe(subscriber);
```

*Edit*

- Related question:

[chaining async method calls - javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39028882/chaining-async-method-calls-javascript)

- With the help of Promises I could transform from synchronous to asynchronous calls:

---

```
foo(){
 return new Promise(resolve=>{
   baa().then(arg=>resolve(arg))
 })
}
```

---

However, I need the other direction, something like:

```
pipe() {
   var result = undefined;
   await asyncCall(()=>{ //await is not allowed here; forces pipe to by async
     result = 5;
   });
   return result;
 }
```

Comment: It is doable in rxjs with for example mergeMap operator. You could check out their source code to see how they solved this use case.

Answer (score 0):

As a work around, I extended the resulting promise with a `subscribe` proxy, calling my actual `subscribe` method:

```
pipe(...operators){

    let observable = this;

    let promise = new Promise(async (resolve) =>{
      for (let operator of operators){
       observable = await this._applyOperator(operator, observable);
      }
      resolve(observable);
    });

    promise.subscribe = (subscriber)=>{
      promise.then(resultingObservable =>{
        resultingObservable.subscribe(subscriber);
      })
    };

    return promise;
}
```

If you know a better solution, please let me know.